# Prove that angles are equal

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle. Point $D$ is on $BC$ edge and $E$ on $AB$. We know that $BD=AC$, $AD=AE$, $AB^2=AC*BC$.
Prove, that $\angle BAD$ $=$ $\angle CEA$ .
I think, that Menelaus' theorem can be helpful there, but I don't know how to solve it.
Sorry for my English .

Comment: this is a problem from an ongoing contest... http://om.edu.pl/sites/default/files/zadania/om/om67_1.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was part of an ongoing contest when it was asked.

Comment: @timon92, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1455556/18398 which is from the same contest.

Comment: @Joel, I know, I reported that thread too

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Why can't it be discussed here now that the contest has ended?

Comment: @Tintarn, a moderator has undeleted your answer because the contest has ended.  If other users with enough reputation see merit in this question, then they can vote to reopen the question so that more answers can be added.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $ab=c^2$ implies that
$$BD \cdot BC=BA^2$$
and hence
$$\frac{BA}{BD}=\frac{BC}{BA}$$
and hence it's easy to see that the triangles $BAD$ and $BCA$ are similar since they share a common angle at $B$ and have the same side ratio.

Thus, we conclude that $\measuredangle EAC=\measuredangle ADB$.

Now, we note that the triangles $BAD$ and $CEA$ must be congruent by the above angle equality and $AE=AD$ as well as $BD=AC$.

And finally this implies that we must also have $\measuredangle CEA=\measuredangle BAD$ as desired.

Comment: this is a problem from an ongoing contest http://om.edu.pl/sites/default/files/zadania/om/om67_1.pdf

please delete the answer

Comment: @timon92: Thanks for the remark. I was not aware of that. But it seems that the omission deadline for that competition has now passed so it's legitimate to discuss it here, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.